# Can Slow be cast outside a room, but go through an open window?

Tags: spells, area-of-effect

My players dived into a building through an open window. Then a witch saw this, and cast slow, targeting 20 feet outside the building. Does the spell go through the window and affect the players, if they are within the 40 foot square?[image]

Comment: What game? Dnd 5e?

Comment: If this question is about D&D 5e, then I think it is a duplicate of this question: [Are creatures affected by the Slow spell if the character who cast it does not know their exact location?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/162042), but please confirm for us what game (and edition if applicable) you are playing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Additional Clarification: The slow spell was "targeting 20 feet outside the building" but the image shows the center point of the affect to be right on the window. Can you clarify that the point of origin was the window? Or adjust as "Targeting 20 square feet of area outside the building, intending for the other 20 sq feet to be inside the building." etc. I originally read this as the point of origin being 20 feet away from the building, to where the edge of the affect would be along the wall of said building.

Comment: Definitely needs the version specified.  Assuming 5e, not sure it's a dup.  Maybe there's a difference because part of the 40-foot cube, which has to be "within range", is on the other side of the wall.